PG_CURSORS behaviour in postgres version 16
I have a cursor declared, open and fetched. Within a loop if I check the counts in pg_cursors, I only get 0. In previous version, PostgreSQL 11, it is working fine. But, I face this issue only in PostgreSQL 16.
Sample code is as below which prints "I did not get inside the loop" even though the cursor hold values:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gis_in.pg_cur_test1()
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    m_cnt int;
    pg_cur CURSOR  FOR SELECT id
      FROM  emp;
     m_bref numeric;
BEGIN   
   open pg_cur;
   fetch pg_cur into m_bref;
   if exists(select 1 from pg_cursors where name = 'pg_cur') then
     loop
          exit when not found;
          raise info 'm_bref is :,%',m_bref;
          fetch pg_cur into m_bref;
     end loop;
   end if;
   raise info 'I did not get inside the loop';
   close pg_cur;
END;
$BODY$;


Slightly offtopic: Why do you use a cursor in the first place? There is hardly any use case for cursors within PL/pgSQL. PL/pgSQL does it automatically for you. I think it's only useful when the function returns a cursor or scrolls the cursor back and forward.

Thanks Frank. This how all the procedures are written. I need to replace "if exists(select 1 from pg_cursors where name = 'pg_cur') then" as pg_cursors doesnt hold records. Please help

Or how can i make sure my pg_cursors hold records. Is there any server level settings required for this

In other words, i want the if exists(select 1 from pg_cursors where name ='cur_name' should work. Please help. Version is 16

PostgreSQL 16 uses unique names for cursors (by default) like <unnamed portal 3>, ... but you can force name by assigning the name to the cursor variable:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gis_in.pg_cur_test1()
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    m_cnt int;
    pg_cur CURSOR  FOR SELECT id
      FROM  emp;
     m_bref numeric;
BEGIN
   -- set custom name for cursor
   pg_cur := 'pg_cur';
   open pg_cur;
   fetch pg_cur into m_bref;
   if exists(select 1 from pg_cursors where name = 'pg_cur') then
     loop
          exit when not found;
          raise info 'm_bref is :,%',m_bref;
          fetch pg_cur into m_bref;
     end loop;
   end if;
   raise info 'I did not get inside the loop';
   close pg_cur;
END;
$BODY$;

Personally I don't understand to usage IF EXISTS(SELECT ... FROM pg_cursors) WHERE  name = 'pg_curs') THEN. It is always true if open statement doesn't fail (for any PostgreSQL version). Probably you want to write some like:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gis_in.pg_cur_test1()
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    m_cnt int;
    pg_cur CURSOR  FOR SELECT id
      FROM  emp;
     m_bref numeric;
BEGIN   
   
   if not exists(select 1 from pg_cursors where name = 'pg_cur') then
     pg_cur := 'pg_cur';
     open pg_cur;
   end if;

   fetch pg_cur into m_bref;
   loop
      exit when not found;
      raise info 'm_bref is :,%',m_bref;
      fetch pg_cur into m_bref;
   end loop;
 end if;
 raise info 'I did not get inside the loop';
 close pg_cur;
END;
$BODY$;


Thank you Pavel. It worked well.
